# Using and saving custom dropdown boxes on user profiles

Tags: users, user-meta, dropdown

Okay, so I'm creating a website and am in need of help for some custom meta fields for user profiles. Currently I have the following in my *functions.php* file:

```
//hooks
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'Add_user_fields' );

function Add_user_fields( $user ) { ?>

<h3 class="sizeShapeH3">Size &amp; Shape</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">Top (neck, shoulders, arms) </label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID ); //there was an extra ) here that was not needed 
            ?>
            <select name="user_top" id="user_top">
                <option value="gotguns" <?php echo ($topselected == "gotguns")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>I got guns</option>
                <option value="yogatop" <?php echo ($topselected == "yogatop")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Yoga top</option>
                <option value="waifish" <?php echo ($topselected == "waifish")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Waif-ish</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">Middle (bust, waist) </label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_middle', $user->ID ); //there was an extra ) here that was not needed 
            ?>
            <select name="user_middle" id="user_middle">
                <option value="handful" <?php echo ($middleselected == "handful")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Perfect handful</option>
                <option value="yogawaist" <?php echo ($middleselected == "yogawaist")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Yoga Waist</option>
                <option value="itsybitsy" <?php echo ($middleselected == "itsybitsy")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Itsy Bitsy</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="dropdown">Bottom (hips/thighs) </label></th>
        <td>
            <?php 
            //get dropdown saved value
            $selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_bottom', $user->ID ); //there was an extra ) here that was not needed 
            ?>
            <select name="user_bottom" id="user_bottom">
                <option value="junktrunk" <?php echo ($bottomselected == "junktrunk")?  'bottomselected="bottomselected"' : '' ?>>Junk in the trunk</option>
                <option value="yogabottom" <?php echo ($bottomselected == "yogabottom")?  'bottomselected="bottomselected"' : '' ?>>Yoga Bottom</option>
                <option value="shrunktrunk" <?php echo ($bottomselected == "shrunktrunk")?  'bottomselected="bottomselected"' : '' ?>>Shrunk in the trunk</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_fields' );

function save_user_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    //save top
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_top', $_POST['user_top'] );

    //save middle
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_middle', $_POST['user_middle'] );

    //save bottom
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user_bottom', $_POST['user_middle'] );
}
```

All of the code seems to work and when I click "Update Profile" it works (I think), but the dropdowns display the first item, instead of the selected item by the user. So if a user selected "Yoga Top" and clicked on "Save", "I Got Guns" is displayed instead of "Yoga Top", which the user selected. Is there anyway I can fix this?

I would really appreciate any help as we are under the gun in terms of time.

Thanks!
-Keenan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be checking for variables that aren't set.

You set `$selected`

```
$selected = get_the_author_meta( 'user_top', $user->ID );
```

But then you check for something called `$topselected`

```
<select name="user_top" id="user_top">
    <option value="gotguns" <?php echo ($topselected == "gotguns")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>I got guns</option>
```

The same thing happns with `$middleselected` and `$bottomselected`

I think your problem is nothing more than a mistake in the code.

Though WordPress has a function called [`selected`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) that would make that a little neater.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. It was pretty late at night so that was a simple mistake.